# Firebreath promise reject slicing exception

Tags: firebreath

Is there a way to pass any meaningful message, not “std::exception” to the promise’s fail callback? In the sources I found the following “void FB::variantDeferred::reject(std::exception e) const” specification. It seems when reject is called with any exception derived from std::exception the slicing happens and the right exception’s message is lost. Is there any workaround but to pass error through success callback?

Answer (score 0):

`std::exception` is simply a base class for creating exceptions in C++.  You can use a number of different methods to pass a specific string back; for example, you could throw a [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error), which accepts a message.

You could also subclass std::exception and provide an implementation of [std::exception::what](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) which returns a useful string representation of what you want.

FireBreath 2.0 will use the error message from e.what() when it creates the Error object.  You can find this in the code, if you're curious how that works:

- [NPAPI](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/2.0/src/NpapiCore/NpapiBrowserHost.cpp#L912)
- [ActiveX](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/2.0/src/ActiveXCore/ComVariantUtil.h#L310)
- [FireWyrm](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/2.0/src/FireWyrm/WyrmVariantUtil.h#L62) (used for Native Messaging)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know FireBreath 2.0 use the error message from std::exception::what. But I meant that FB::variantDeferred::reject(std::exception e) gets the exception by value and std::exception's copy-constructor is called. While copying the actual value of e.what() is lost and for e.what() is used default implementation of  std::exception::what which returns standard message "std::Exception". I tried to use std::runtime_error, but message which I passed into it was also lost. And I again got "std::Exception" in JavaScript.

Comment: Ahh; I do see what you mean.  Sounds like a bug; I'd welcome a pull request to deal with this.  I'll probably fix it eventually, but I don't know how soon I will be able to

Comment: Ok. I will try to fix it and make a pull request.